# How to call a .py file to execute using JMeter

Tags: python, jmeter

I have created a Python Script that basically test Web API. (i.e DynamicWebAPIResponse.py)

Above file internally call two files.

1. DynamicWebAPI.ini (Configuration file).
2. decript.exe (For encryption & description).

How it would be possible to execute the DynamicWebAPIResponse.py file Using JMeter?
Also use two dependent file when required?

Note : DynamicWebAPIResponse.py consist of 2000+ lines of code.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: [OS_Process_Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler) does not work?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options:

1. Call the file normally using [OS Process Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler), check out [How to Run External Commands and Programs Locally and Remotely from JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter/) article for more details
2. Put [Jython](https://www.jython.org/) library to [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath), this way you will be able to use Python code in the [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223)

   [image]