# JMeter - Error when using Jython/Python Engine in JSR223 Sampler "Cannot find Engine"

Tags: python, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jsr223

Using [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60450291/how-to-call-a-py-file-to-execute-using-jmeter/60486183#60486183), I created a test plan to call a python script.

I ran the script with the Log Viewer open.

The JMeter log says:

```
2022-03-03 13:44:32,118 ERROR o.a.j.p.j.s.JSR223Sampler: Problem in JSR223 script JSR223 Sampler, message: javax.script.ScriptException: Cannot find engine named: 'python', ensure you set language field in JSR223 Test Element: JSR223 Sampler
javax.script.ScriptException: Cannot find engine named: 'python', ensure you set language field in JSR223 Test Element: JSR223 Sampler
    at org.apache.jmeter.util.JSR223TestElement.getScriptEngine(JSR223TestElement.java:100) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JSR223Sampler.sample(JSR223Sampler.java:69) [ApacheJMeter_java.jar:5.4.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:638) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:558) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:489) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:256) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.3]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_311]
```

Which is strange, because I put the Jython JAR in the JMeter lib folder

[image]

, restarted JMeter, and saw the menu:

[image]

I am using JMeter 5.4.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It might be the problem with your `jython.jar` file, try downloading i.e. [`jython-standalone-2.7.2.jar`](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/python/jython-standalone/2.7.2/jython-standalone-2.7.2.jar) library to "lib" folder of your JMeter installation

   I don't know how did you get this `python` binding in the dropdown, my expectation is that it should be `jython`

   [image]
2. JMeter restart will be required to pick up the .jar
3. Be aware that [recommended scripting language is Groovy](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting), the main reason is performance, check out [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) guide for more information.

   Moreover, Jython is stuck at Python version 2.7 and it was discontinued on 1st of Jan 2020 so it might be the case you won't be able to re-use your Python code in JSR223 Test Elements, if your code is in Python 3 maybe it worth considering running it using [OS Process Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler)?

Comment: Yes, OS Process Sampler was my next option.

And, yes, I also have jython in the drop-down.